# toggle using remove and add class

Tags: jquery

```js
$('#x').click(function(){
  $('#x').removeClass('linex').addClass('line');
})
```

```css
.line {
color: red;
}

.linex {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='x' class='max linex'>line</div>
```

In my code here, I turn the class into `line(red)` when i click on the div, But i want it to be reversible , So when i click again while it is in `line` to be turned again into `linex(blue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your js to this :

```
$('#x').click(function(){
  $('#x').toggleClass('line linex');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$('#x').click(function(){
  $('#x').toggleClass('linex').toggleClass('line');
})
```

```css
.line {
color: red;
}

.linex {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='x' class='max linex'>line</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toggleClass("line")` on your function.
no need to toggle two class just class line is enoughbecause your div at the first has class line and function overwrite it.

```
$('#x').click(function(){
  $('#x').toggleClass('line');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it somewhat easier. My proposed solution will be to add default style of color:red to the div. That means your div's text color will be red. When you click the div, all you have to do is just toggle linex class. This will add the class if not present or remove the class if present and will make your code shorter and nicer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to look for that id again in the dom...it is already available as `this` in the event handler.

Use space separated classes in [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$('#x').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('linex line');
});
```

```css
.line {
color: red;
}

.linex {
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='x' class='max linex'>line</div>
```